# how to find the port number of solr in windows cmd?

Tags: solr

since I'm new to the Solr server. I don't know how can I find the port number of Solr using CMD in windows?. if any knows please do help in finding thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, Solr is running on the port **8983**. However, it may happen, that you have Solr server which is running on some different port. In this case you could check status of Solr server by running command:

```
./bin/solr.cmd status
```

which would provide information like this, if you have something running:

```
Found 1 Solr nodes: 

Solr process 9713 running on port 8983
```

Comment: @vigneshwaransundarrajan if this answer helped you - consider marked it as accepted and upvote it